# sublime text 3 extend syntax highlighting

Tags: sublime-syntax

I'm using package control version of sublime-text plugin [SublimeSKP](https://github.com/nojanath/SublimeKSP), 
which is being automatically updated. Recently I've added possibility of extending plugin compiler with users-defind functions. And now I'm interesting of making my new "plugins built-in functions and keywords" being highlighted in addition to the main automatically updated package, without completely rewriting sublime-syntax file after every update. Is it possible?

Should it be an separated sublime-syntax which will look for particular scopes inside the source, don't taking part in the default chosen syntax?